# React Typescript tests - Target container is not a DOM element

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-test-renderer

I'm new to testing React/Typescript apps.

command (alias for `react-scripts test`):

```
yarn test
```

output:

```
 FAIL  src/containers/pages/Feature/Feature.test.tsx
  ● Test suite failed to run

    Target container is not a DOM element.

      17 | const { store, persistor } = configureStore(history, initialState);
      18 | 
    > 19 | ReactDOM.render(
         |          ^
      20 |   <Provider store={store}>
      21 |     <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistor}>
      22 |       <ConnectedRouter history={history}>

      at Object.render (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:27596:13)
      at Object.render (src/index.tsx:19:10)
```

simple test code:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { create } from 'react-test-renderer';
import Feature from "./Feature";

describe('Feature page component', () => {
  test('matches the snapshot', () => {
    const feature = create(
      <Feature />,
    );
    expect(feature.toJSON()).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
});
```

src/index.tsx file in fact contains `ReactDOM.render()` call that fails in tests, but what's a working alternative?

Note: the app itself works fine, it's just failing to run in test mode.

---

in src/index.tsx file I have:

```
export const history = createBrowserHistory({
  basename: '/admin',
});
const initialState: StoreState = (undefined as unknown) as StoreState;
const { store, persistor } = configureStore(history, initialState);
```

and then in services and sagas I import `history` and `store` from index.tsx. may it be the problem causing tests to fail?

---

I tried to extract `history` and `store` to a separate file (as suggested by commenters). Now the above code is inside `src/initialState.ts`.

- Good news: error "Target container is not a DOM element" is gone!
- Bad news: I get a new error (which can be an independent problem, so extracted to a [separate question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62328584/1429387))

Comment: looks like you are declaring `Feature`....

Comment: it looks like something is trying to render your `index.tsx`....

Comment: @DanielA.White sorry, changed `Feature` to `feature` in question.

Comment: What is it you're currently looking for to test? In general, you would not test the index.ts which renders your application to the dom. you would either test everything inside your React.render method since this is what will happen within your test as well. The react components in your tests will be rendered to a virtual dom.

Comment: @DanielA.White added details to the bottom of the question.

Comment: @takethefake a functional React component named `Feature`. it's a page consisting of other components.

Comment: @naXa, does the `Feature` component currently contain a `ReactDOM.render` method inside?

Comment: @takethefake no, it doesn't. File search shows that `ReactDOM.render` method is present only in one place - src/index.tsx.

Comment: @naXa, does my answer solve your problem or do you have any further questions?

Comment: @takethefake I'm not sure. Maybe it solves, or maybe just moves the problem to another level. give me 10 minutes to add new details to the question.

Comment: @takethefake please take a look again

Comment: @naXa this is a whole other question, please accept my answer and create a new question for the amcharts testerror but feel free to ping me!

Comment: @takethefake agree, no problem. I'll ask a new question, but first I need to look for possible duplicates.

Comment: @takethefake new question: [Encountered an unexpected token on imported file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62328584/1429387).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem that is happening in your test right now is that you want to test a component that imports something from `index.tsx`. When your're importing from `index.tsx` `ReactDOM.render` is called as well and your tests fail.

> Ensure to not import anything from `index.tsx` and move your logic you've defined there in a separate file.

In general, you would have an index file for your Application e.g.:`index.tsx` which imports your `App.tsx` and just cares about rendering the React component to the dom with `ReactDOM.render`.

In the `App.tsx` you would define all components like `Provider`, `PersistGate`, or even `Feature`

when you're testing your component you want to be sure it doesn't include the `ReactDOM.render`, because what you're doing when testing is rendering the Component under test inside a virtual dom and unfortunately this clashes with `ReactDOM.render`

I've provided an example on how I would set something like this up in a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/quirky-cray-l4ppw?file=/src/Feature.test.tsx)

Nowadays I prefer testing components with [@testing-library/react](https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/intro) instead of `react-test-renderer` which has also become the default testing library with `create-react-app`.